# Can I tell whether this expression is positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can I say that the following is greater than zero

$$ \frac{2 \sqrt{xy} - y}{2(z+1)},$$

when $x \leq 2y \leq z$? What if, instead, $2y \leq z \leq x $?

For the second condition i.e, $2y \leq z \leq x $, I think the following can be done
$$ \frac{2 \sqrt{xy} - y}{2(z+1)}\geq \frac{(2\sqrt{2}-1)y }{2(z+1)} >0.$$

Is my analysis correct?

Thanks

Comment: what's happening with $\sqrt{xy}$ if $x=-1$ and $y =1$?

Comment: i think we have lost some informations

Comment: @Surb they are all positive integers, i have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Surb thanks, I have added another condition, can you please check the next one..

Comment: @Henry: Please, if you have a question you intend to ask, ask it. If you are not sure exactly what question you are trying to ask, say so. It's not polite to keep changing your question like this.

Comment: @EricStucky I have remembered to add the second condition later, this is the main change I have made?

Comment: @EricStucky the conditions I gave are separate conditions...

Comment: @EricStucky thanks no problem.

Comment: I don't mean this to be an open-close war, but the majority of the votes to close came before the second paragraph was added, which I believe suffices as "context"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the denominator must be strictly positive, so the sign of the numerator determines the sign of the expression.

Therefore, we hope that $2\sqrt{xy}-y> 0$. This is equivalent to $4xy\geq y^2$, or since $y\neq 0$ we divide through to find $x> \frac14y$.

However, we are restricted to choose $x$ such that either $x\leq 2y$ or $x\geq 2y$.

In the former condition, there are of course counterexamples. In the latter, however, since $y$ is positive we have $2y>\frac14 y$ and therefore $x\geq\frac14y$.

(Note that the integer restriction is never used. Moreover, it is an easy exercise to show that if $y$ is negative, then the former condition $x\leq 2y$ makes the fraction positive instead.)

Comment: your answer is wrong if $y\ne 0$ you must do case work, for $y<0$ we obtain $4x\le y$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I don't understand what you mean, can you please explaine more...$y$ is in my question a positive